# How to replace the anomalous data in time-series analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, anomaly-detection

I applied an isolation forest algorithm to identify the anomalous data in my time series. Now I want to replace those outliers before feeding them into a machine learning model. How can we replace those outliers in time series analysis?

Comment: It depends on number of outliers present the data. If the outliers are a very negligible fraction of the total data, you can drop them, but if the outliers are present in a larger amount then it is better to fit an other model for those.

Comment: @Priya Thank you for your suggestions. Are you sure about removing the outlier from time-series data? Since there are temporal relationships among the values, I am confused to drop the anomalous data from the whole time series. Could you please give any hints about the model you suggested for a larger amount of outliers?

Comment: Can you illustrate the nature of your outliers? Answers very much depend on that.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the kind of data and what you want to do. Consider two scenarios that are time-dependent.

1. Predicting the target variable depending on sensor measurements.

In this case, you can neglect the sensor transmission errors to create a cleaner dataset for the other algorithms to use.

2. Fraud Detection.

In this case, you want to detect the pattern when the anomaly will be created so you can't drop or replace the outlier because you are analyzing the outlier itself.

There is a forecast package in R `tsclean()`. The `tsclean()` function will fit a robust trend using loess (for non-seasonal series), or robust trend and seasonal components using STL (for seasonal series).

For non-seasonal time series, outliers are replaced by linear interpolation. For seasonal time series, the seasonal component from the STL fit is removed and the seasonally adjusted series is linearly interpolated to replace the outliers, before adding back the trend and seasonal components to the result.